# Excel : find in the middle of length

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2002

i have some of length like this

```
A002 30/2Z 0.25 KG/CONE_HS OIM    - I NEED ->0.25 KG
A003 TEX 22272Z 0.50 KG/CONE_PAP3-000 - I NEED ->0.50 KG
```

the blank is not fix.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: will `KG` always follow by `/`? also does the weight always show in two decimal places (could it be a whole number in some case)?

Comment: yes, some time the weight like 1 KG/CONE or 2 lbs/cone or 1000 yds/cone.

Comment: if the number is greater than 1000, will it be shown as `1000 KG` or `1,000 KG`? Also, do you need to extract the unit (KG, LBS) or you are good with just the number value without the unit?

Comment: Looks like the only consistent part of the strong is "/CONE". Right?

Comment: KG AND LBS I CAN SPLIT. Thanks so much Terry W.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `B2`, formula copied down :

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A2,SEARCH("/cone",A2)-1)," ",REPT(" ",99)),199))
```

[image]

Comment: Very much thanks for your attention, bosco_yip.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>FILTERXML()</kbd> may be best fit for you.

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[.*0=0]")
```

[image]

- `"<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>"` will construct a valid XML string to process by <kbd>FILTERXML()</kbd> formula.
- XPATH parameter `//s[.*0=0]` will filter only numbers.
- If you have more than one number in same cell then you may need to specify position of number you want to return.

More about `FILTERXML()` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61837696/excel-extract-substrings-from-string-using-filterxml) from JvdV

Comment: I am use  Excel 2002 have not  filterxml()